# You can 'promote' access specification through inheritance, can you ever 'demote' access specification?

Tags: c++, inheritance

By 'promote' I mean make access more restrictive and by 'demote' I mean make less restrictive.

For example, when `class B` is derived from `class A` using `: protected` or `: private` then the public members of A get promoted, to protected and private, respectively.

Could some `class C` ever come in and derive itself from `class B`, while at the same time demoting the inherited members of class A back to their original access specifications?

Comment: i feel your usage of "promote" and "demote" should be swap around.

Comment: you must be some sort of hippy, thinking of less restrictions as a promotion :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `protected` derivation, then class `C` could indeed give access to the protected members, by creating an appropriate wrapper:

```
class A {
public:
  void F();
};

class B : protected A { };

class C : public B {
public:
  using B::F;
};
```

This also can be made to work with data members:

```
class A {
public:
  int n;
};

class B : protected A { };

class C : public B {
public:
  using B::n;
  C() : n(this->B::n) { }
};
```

With `private` inheritance this is not directly possible, because `C` cannot itself access members in `A`.. However, if `B` is derived from `A` using `private virtual` inheritance, it becomes possible again:

```
class A {
public:
  void F();
};

class B : private virtual A { };

class C : public B, public virtual A { };

int main() {
  C x;
  x.F();
  return 0;
}
```

This works because with `virtual` inheritance, `C` can derive directly from the *same instance* of `A` as `B`, but with a different access specifier.

Comment: Okay, I'm well on my way to understanding your awesome answer. For the protected case, it works! Super cool wrapper. I even changed class `A` to `class A { protected: void F(); };` and then you can still call `c.F()` but you can't call `a.F()` which I think is super funny and awesome. Making it private kills the fun. Can you get the same trick to work on data? I guess you'd need some sort of wrapper, so you'd always end up calling a function and needing `()` when you try to get at the value? Still working on understanding the virtual part of your answer...

Comment: @Jimmy, added an example of data members

Comment: That is excellent.  Works just like the function part (and protected stays protected in class A).  Worst of all, I think I fully get it.  It's like class C is saying to the world "No baby, no.  I'm not a class C.  I'm a class B.  I promise I'll be gentle." ...  or something like that ...  so can you get that to jump up two levels?  I've never had much luck with chained scope resolution operators.

Comment: `using A::F;` is rather less hacky than writing wrapper functions or adding reference members.

Answer (score 3):

A `using` declaration can give access to public or protected members of protected base classes:

```
struct A {int x;};
struct B : protected A {};

struct C : B
{
    using A::x;  // publicly accessible
}
```

Obviously, private members and base classes aren't available to `C`, so you can't reduce the restrictions on them.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, what would be the point of having `private` or `protected` inheritance if I can just create another derived that class that blows away the intermediate class' access restrictions and makes everything `public`?

Comment: I actually thought about that before asking my question... at first I only thought of blowing things away by making them public, but then I thought more deeply about moving private things back to being protected. I think that would be fun. Too bad for me I guess.

Comment: Some argue (and perhaps I agree) against protected methods more generally for a similar reason. You can always make a wrapper exposing the same function under a new name.

Answer (score 0):

**No**.
Because, when `class C` derives `class B`; it doesn't know about the original access specifiers of `class A`. It just respects the access specifiers in `class B`.